# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../config.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Trying to load external config file in nodejs for AWS SES with below code.

```
aws.config.loadFromPath('../config.json');
```

It throws this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../config.json'
```

Now the file is there on that location but above code doesn't see it.

Any quick solution please?

UPDATE

It happens both locally and on the server.

Comment: try `./../config.json`

Comment: Same error with that path too. just tried it.

Comment: may be this `process.cwd()+'./../config.json'`

Comment: That returns this `/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing final '@domain'`

Comment: use SSM(Systems Manager) parameter store to keep your configuration values and access through it.

Comment: Use fs.existsSync('../config.json') to make sure that it actually exists at that relative path. Then fs.readFileSync() to check you can read the contents. Then pass the contents to JSON.parse() to verify that it's valid JSON. Then investigate the requirements of aws.config.loadFromPath().

Comment: @RajanLagah `process.cwd()+'/config.json'` worked somehow. Thanks

Comment: glad to hear that,I helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use `__dirname`

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const path = require('path')
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '/config.json')

AWS.config.loadFromPath(dirPath)
```